# Texstudio Completer showing the wrong document

Tags: math-mode, texstudio

I am recently facing a problem with the Completer in texstudio.

When I type for example \to, I saw the whole manual of Math symbols, rather than the user manual of the $\to$ symbol. This also makes the completer very slow and I have no choice but turn the completer off. This happens to all the symbols within this doc: [16.2 Math symbols](http://joshua.smcvt.edu/latex2e/Math-symbols.html)

It used to correctly show the manual of the symbol, but all of a sudden it goes wrong. I cannot remember if I did something with the configuration. But even if I restored the configuration to default it changes nothing.

This is what I see now: 
[image: what I see]

This is what it used to be and I expect:
[image: what it used to be]

Anyone has an idea? Thanks!

Comment: Whilst you may get feedback from users here Your issue is very specific to TeXstudio so is best to check if it has already been answered at their support on GitHub see https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/issues then if it is not already a closed item, then raise your query there

Comment: As a temporary fix, you could turn of the 'ToolTip-Help' option (Options > Completion > ToolTip-Help). This would allow you to keep the 'completion' enabled.