# TeXstudio or TeXlive gives wrong package description

Tags: packages, texlive, texstudio, description

I just started using LaTeX with these softwares but when i want to read package or tools description it gives me wrong ones for almost every description, only some are right (textheight and textwidth for instance).
I tried to reinstall but it didn't work..

I have this issue only on windows, not linux.

Any hints? Where are the package descriptions located? Is there something I should wipe somewhere?

[image: TeXstudio wrong package description]

Comment: well it's not package it's command description, just noticed... sorry

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se.  There is no global command reference, since packages and classes can define their own macros. For most of the core LaTeX macros you should consult a good introduction to LaTeX, or possibly the LaTeX Wikibook.  For TeX itself, read the TeXBook or TeX by Topic. For other macros, you need to read the individual package documentation, which means you have to have an idea of which package defined the macro. There are many ways to read package documentation. See [How to find the documentation for a package?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/380019).

Comment: similar to same issue https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/471476/texstudio-completer-showing-the-wrong-document suggest approach support via https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/issues